# How do I use toISOString() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

I am using currentDate.toISOString(), which gives output in the format of "2013-01-15T12:08:54.135Z".

But I need the date should be formatted as "2013-01-15T12:08:54-06:00".

Here -06:00 may be the timezone.

Answer (score 2):

This function only builds ISO formatted strings, as defined by [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

To build a differently formatted string you can

- build your own function using the `get*` functions of [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (especially [getTimeZoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset))
- use a library like [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

date.js has a convenient [toString](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString) function. And you may use [many identifiers](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers), if you import [extras.js](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/src/extras.js?r=155), among them

> P      Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and
>   minutes      "+02:00", "-06:00"